# Cast value to generic type to pass it to a generic function

Tags: swift, generics, casting

I have a generic function `foo()` which takes an argument `p` whose  type conforms to `Proto`. `Proto` and some types conforming to it are defined in another module and can't be changed.

`foo()` should dynamically check the type of `p` and handle some types in a specific way. Some of the types it should handle are generic themselves but the type parameters again conform to `Proto` and thus the nested values could be handled by `foo()` again:

```swift
protocol Proto {}
struct A: Proto { let value: Int }
struct B<P: Proto>: Proto { let value: P }

func foo<P: Proto>(_ p: P) -> Int {
    if let a = p as? A {
        return a.value
    } else if let b = p as? B<???> {
        // If we could cast this to `B<T>` with an unknown T, we could pass it to foo<T>().
        return 2 * foo(b.value)
    } else {
        // Handle unknown types in a generic way.
        fatalError()
    }
}

print(foo(A(value: 1)))
print(foo(B(value: A(value: 2))))
print(foo(B(value: B(value: A(value: 3)))))
```

How can I handle values to type `B<T>` for an arbitrary `T` and call `foo()` on the nested value?

Comment: Does `Proto` have any associated types or usage of `Self` types? Or asked in a different way, can `foo` be declared as `func foo(_ p: Proto) -> Int`?

Comment: @Sweeper In the project where this came up, `Proto` does have associated types. But I'd be interested in solutions for either case (or both cases) since I didn't find a solution for either case.

Comment: @Sweeper Thinking about it, wouldn't writing the function as `foo(_ p: Proto)` possibly make it harder for the compiler to optimize its implementation (especially the type cases) because `p` would be passed as a boxed existential to a single instance of the function, where the generic function could be instantiated for specific types allowing the casts to be eliminated?

Comment: No, the compiler _wouldn't_ know about the specific types that's going to be passed in, because it doesn't know what the `???` is, and this is precisely why this is not possible if the protocol has associated types. `b.value` must be of an existential type. Can you state what concrete type `b.value` is? No. If you could, you could have just written it in the place of `???`.

Comment: @Sweeper Whats up with the arrogant tone? o.O First of all, I was simply asking a technical question and second, your statement is false. In each case in my example code where `foo()` is called, the type of `P` is known statically. When instantiating the function for cases where `P` is some `B`, the type argument of `B` is also known (`A` in the second call to `foo()`, `B<A>` in the third call). In the case where `foo()` is not instantiated and a generic version is used by the compiler instead, a protocol witness table for `P` is passed to `foo()`.

Comment: In the case that `P` is some `B`, the witness table will contain a reference to the protocol witness table for `B.P`, which could be passed to the recursive call to `foo()`. So in either case there's enough information to pass `p.value` to `foo()` without resorting to existentials.

Answer (score 1):

Every expression has a type. Think about what the type of `b.value` would be if this were possible. There is no concrete type that it can be, otherwise you'd be replacing `???` with that type. It must be the existential `Proto` then, but in that case, you wouldn't be able to call `foo` with `b.value`, because `Proto` doesn't satisfy the generic constraint of `P: Proto`. Protocols don't conform to themselves, after all. [See this excellent explanation by Hamish if you are not sure why.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/5133585)

Well, what if we declare `foo` to be non-generic?

```
func foo(_ p: Proto) -> Int
```

Then this can be solved.

You can declare a protocol that requires a `value` of type `Proto`:

```
protocol HasProtoValue {
    var protoValue: Proto { get }
}
```

Then make an extension on `B` to conform to it:

```
extension B : HasProtoValue {
    var protoValue: Proto { value }
}
```

Now you can check for `HasProtoValue` instead:

```
func foo(_ p: Proto) -> Int {
    if let a = p as? A {
        return a.value
    } else if let b = p as? HasProtoValue {
        return 2 * foo(b.protoValue)
    } else {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

Note that `b.value` has been replaced with `b.protoValue`, which has the type `Proto`. Note that this is an existential, and we still don't know which specific conformance of `Proto` it is.

Comment: There are two limitations I think should be noted: `Proto` cannot have associated types (because it is used as an existential type in the updated signature of `foo()`) and this requires that a new protocol is added for each type that should be handled differently (e.g. if `C` also had a `let value` but the value computed from it should be multiplied by `2` instead of `3`). See my answer for an approach without these two limitations.

Answer (score 1):

The cases of `foo()` which are used to handle some types specially can be moved to a new protocol `FooImpl`. For each such type, a conformance to `FooImpl` is added via an extension:

```swift
protocol Proto {}
struct A: Proto { let value: Int }
struct B<P: Proto>: Proto { let value: P }

protocol FooImpl {
    func fooImpl() -> Int
}

extension A: FooImpl {
    func fooImpl() -> Int {
        return value
    }
}

extension B: FooImpl {
    func fooImpl() -> Int {
        return 2 * foo(value)
    }
}

func foo<P: Proto>(_ p: P) -> Int {
    if let x = p as? FooImpl {
        return x.fooImpl()
    } else {
        fatalError()
    }
}

print(foo(A(value: 1)))  # prints "1"
print(foo(B(value: A(value: 2))))  # prints "4"
print(foo(B(value: B(value: A(value: 3)))))  # prints "12"
```

This works because protocol `FooImpl` can be used as an existential type on which `fooImpl()` can be called.

Comment: Oh gosh, that's brilliant. Now that I see this, I realised I never even thought about changing the entire implementation of `foo`, and sort of just focused on what `B<???>` could be. I guess I need to think outside of the box more...